# 'Missing } after property list. (line 3, file "Code")'

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to implement what looks to be a simple [code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGMIttLXpo4):

```
function eventosAulaMagna( namedValues ) {

  var options = {description: namedValues.Nombre de la Actividad[0], {guests: namedValues.Nombre[0]};  
  var cEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName( "Aula Magna" )[0].createEvent(namedValues.Nombre de la Actividad, new Date(namedValues.Fecha y Hora de Inicio de la Actividad), new Date(namedValues.Fecha y Hora de Término de la Actividad), options);

}
```

I found on YouTube, but keep getting:

> Missing } after property list. (line 3, file "Code")

Might someone be good enough to explain please?

Comment: Tip: the number of `{` and `}` need to be balanced. Even if you fixed that particular problem though, you'll encounter many more on the next line. That doesn't even begin to be valid syntax, and we could at best guess as to what it is you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 2):

Your number of `{` and `}` in `options` do not match.

Also you are using invalid property names `namedValues.Nombre de la Actividad` is not a valid property name since it has spaces in it.
You have to use it as `namedValues["Nombre de la Actividad"]`.

I assume you meant to do something like this:

```
function eventosAulaMagna( namedValues ) {

    var options = {
        description: namedValues["Nombre de la Actividad"][0],
        guests: namedValues.Nombre[0]
    };  
    var cEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName( "Aula Magna" )[0].createEvent(
        namedValues["Nombre de la Actividad"],
        new Date(namedValues["Fecha y Hora de Inicio de la Actividad"]),
        new Date(namedValues["Fecha y Hora de Término de la Actividad"]),
        options
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you exactly where the problem is: `{description: namedValues.Nombre de la Actividad[0], {guests: namedValues.Nombre[0]};` has two open braces, and only one close. You need to strip the one before `guests` to make a single object with two names.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer at the code on the 2nd line

```
var options = {description:...
```

you will see that you do not have an ending } to match the first { in the line.
This should end with

```
...{guests: namedValues.Nombre[0]}};
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need an extra `}` at the end of your line 3. You never closed the property. This will at least fix the current error, but you are bound to get more errors.

```
var options = {description: namedValues.Nombre de la Actividad[0], {guests: namedValues.Nombre[0]}};
```